# How to make ionic popup blink?

Tags: colors, background, popup, ionic-framework

I want to make a ionic popup blinks after a timeout. I just don't know how to change background color dynamically, after opened.
Someone has any idea?

Comment: Adding some code snippets on how you've attempted to do it so far would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your popup a custom CSS class as described in the [official documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/):

```
$ionicPopup.show({
    cssClass: "blink-popup",
    ...
});
```

And then you can style your popup using CSS:

```
.blink-popup.popup-container .popup {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Code found here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-use-custom-css-in-popup/22414/5

And some more details on customizing your popup: http://www.codeandyou.com/2015/08/How-to-customize-color-and-theme-of-ionic-popup.html